# Get value of an optional class field

Tags: scala

Let's suppose I have a class Toto with two optional fields  :

```
case class Toto(a : Option[Int], b: Option[Int])
```

And a class Titi with one optional Toto :

```
case class Titi(c : Option[Toto])
```

We create an instance of a class Titi :

```
val test = Titi(Some(Toto(Some(1),Some(2))))
```

Now I want to access the second field of Toto in Titi variable by supposing that Titi or b can be equal to None but this statement is impossible :

```
test.c.getOrElse("Something").b.getOrElse(0)
```

How do I proceed to do so ?

Comment: What’s wrong with getOrElse?

Answer (score 9):

You should use flatMap:

```
test.c.flatMap(_.b).getOrElse(0)
```

In a case in any place in the hierarchy there is `None` 0 will be returned.
If you have even a deeper object hierarchy with properties returning `Option` you can chain `flatMap`:

```
test.c
 .flatMap(_.b)
 .flatMap(_.d)
//...etc
```

Scala also has also the special syntax for unwrapping deeply nested monadic types,  called `for comprehension`:

```
val result = for {
   c <- test.c
   a <- c.a
} yield a

result.getOrElse(0)
```

Under the hood, it is compiled to similar code as chained `flatMap`.

This basically works like this:

If `c` is `None` to gets directly to `getOrElse` and returns 0
If it's `Some` then it checks `b`, if it's None it goes to `getOrElse` if not then value wrapped in `Some` is returned.

In case you would want to return something different distinguishing which `Option` is None, then I would just use `match`:

```
test.c match {
   case Some(c) => c.getOrElse(0)
   // if you return String in one branch and integer in other then inferred type would be Any!
   case None    => "Something" 
}
```

Comment: Can't I use getOrElse for c also ? In my case c can be None, when it's Some ... I need to get the value of b

Comment: @Gatsby I edited my answer. That solution with `flatMap` shortcircuits in case there is `None` in any place in the hierarchy. If you need to distinguish which `Option` is `None`, then use solution with `match`  or that proposed by Pedro.

Answer (score 2):

Your val test is wrong, it should be this

```
val test = Titi(Some(Toto(Some(1),Some(2))))
```

Other thing, in the getOrElse, you have to put a type that makes sense

```
test.c.getOrElse(Toto(None,None))
```

Comment: Sorry I mistaken about the syntax. I meant Some instead of Option, I corrected it

Comment: now with this expression you onyl need to do ".b" to get the second parameter

Comment: I want to get the value of b when c is equals to Some(Titi(Some(1),Some(2))) for example

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve it by pattern matching

```
val test: Titi = Titi(Some(Toto(Some(1), None)))
val res = test.c match {
case Some(Toto(_, Some(x))) => x
case _ => 0
}
```

result:

```
0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val x = test match {
    case Titi(x) => {
      x match {
        case Some(x) => {
          x.b match {
            case Some(z) => z
            case None    => 1
          }
        }
        case None => 1
      }
    }
    case _ => 1
  } //> x  : Int = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

u can use fold

```
test.c.fold(0)(_.b.fold(0)(i => i))
```